# Lighting reversed on single object

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, light

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpo5V.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpo5V.png)I'm making an animation by editing a previous created one. 
I'm using version 2.73 on an old Dell laptop with Vista OS and the render engine is Blender Render.

There is a single light source (sun) above the 4 objects in the scene.  3 were newly created, one is from the older animation.  All objects are being rendered (Blender Render) as textures. The lighting appears correct (light on top, shaded below) **except** the old object which appears reversed (dark on top, light on bottom).  The camera view has been changed in the new animation.

[image: PNG Frame]

It's the torpedo that appears lit from below instead of above.

If I open the blender file I started editing into the new one, then import an underwater mine I created in the second version, without changing the camera view or lighting, the problem is reversed. There the torpedo is lit correctly but the mine is backwards

[image: pic 2].

I think I've narrowed the issue down to being related to using textures in the rendering.  The problem doesn't exist with view port shading set to materials. As you can see from this picture:

[image: pic 3]

Unfortunately I need to render as textures for later objects appearing in the animation.  Hope this helps point to the possible problem.

Is there a legacy aspect of the old object (shading correct previously) overriding the new camera positioning, or as a relatively new user, am I overlooking something simple I don't know about? Open to any suggestions that point me in the right direction, but I currently can't include the file for inspection, sorry.  Much appreciation.

[![Fixed Object]
Followup:  I continue to have major system errors (runtime, display driver, etc. frequent crashes) computer/application wide.  Wanted to send a view (see pic 4) of the newly created mine object among the older version to illustrate that whatever the problem was, it was surely operator error on my part.  The new object renders correctly.

Comment: Correction.  Objects are rendered as textures, not materials as stated in my question.

Comment: Don't you think some pictures could help to understand what you are saying here?

Comment: In addition to what lemon said... which render engine? Complete and accurate information really matters, you know... ;-)

Comment: What additional information do you require?  I'll try to provide everything within my limited knowledge and experience with Blender. I'm open to just speculation or opinions that directs me toward a more productive search for a solution myself.  I haven't found any threads that address this anomaly specifically yet, and my general research about lighting, rendering, etc, has fallen short.  I am confident though, it is likely operator error on my part, and not a bug.  Thanks, I appreciate any input.

Comment: What are the Blender versions involved here (the old model and what you have now) ? (if you respond please use @lemon or I won't see any notification)

Comment: @lemon                                                                              I updated the original post with the information you requested.

Comment: @SwanSong2 it would be easier to help you if you upload your file.

Comment: @cegaton  Unfortunately, it's about 180 MB, which is why I was reluctant to upload files in my original post.

Comment: You don't need to upload the whole thing. Isolate the element you are having issues with, keep the lighting and delete the rest.

Comment: @cegaton  I'll try doing that, but it may take a while,

Comment: Have you checked the object's normals? This is a very weird problem... Try pressing Ctrl-N

Comment: @someonewithpc  Normals look OK as near as I can tell.

Comment: @cegaton  Having other trouble with my system, getting the file small enough, and getting Userscript installed to upload it.  I'll keep trying, but I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload, then add the resluting link as part of the text for your question.

Comment: @cegaton  Thanks, got that part taken care of, but the computer and internet connection are not cooperating.  I was able to determine (I think) that the problem exists with the newer created Mine object rather than the older Torpedo.  [ Both created on v. 273] Need to resolve that issue or upload both. I'm looking closer there while I try to solve the continuing system problem.  I'll flag you in a comment when it;s ready.

Comment: if that can help, there is a "compress" option if you "save as" your file.

Comment: @lemon    I apologize for my late responses to all.  This laptop may have reached it's useful lifetime. Now almost every program is crashing including Blender.   If Blender will run, I've realized that recreating the object from scratch until the lighting issue presents itself will be easier than troubleshooting the problem without the information you'd need to fix it.  Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.  I'll try to be better prepared before I ask for help next time.  Cheers

Comment: @lemon & others See follow-up edit to original post.  I can't seem to find the check mark to highlight to consider my question answered and close the post, but wanted to thank you and all the others for trying to help.